# Generating Java Sources with sbt JFlex plugin

Tags: sbt, jflex

I am pulling my hair using the [sbt-jflex](https://github.com/dlwh/sbt-jflex) plugin to generate Java sources via JFlex, before the main javac phase of sbt (0.12).

The plugin is a clone of the ANTLR plugin, and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425863/sbt-and-antlr-got-simple-example) which shows how to use the latter.

So I have the following in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalanlp" % "sbt-jflex" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

And this in `./build.sbt`:

```
jflexSettings

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= generate in jflex
```

But I must be either doing something wrong, or the javac phase comes before the source generators, because when I run `sbt compile`, I never see the message `"JFlex: Using JFlex version X to generate source files"`. Instead sbt goes straight to compile the Java sources

```
[info] Compiling 91 Java sources to ...
```

And then fails because the JFlex output is missing at that stage. Running `source-directories` shows that `src/main/jflex` is indeed included, as is `target/src_managed/main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with injecting debug prints, I found that the sbt-jflex plugin assumes sources are in `src/main/flex` whereas my project has them in `src/main/jflex`. Adding the following fixes it:

```
sourceDirectory in jflex <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile) { _ / "jflex" }
```